# How to get rid of a single entry of the windows explorer context menu that is permanently displayed?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, context-menu

I have a very strange problem. For some hours now a single entry of the windows explorer's context menu (actually the "Copy" entry) is permanently displayed. It's top most in the z Buffer obviously since it overlays all other windows. I killed all running explorer processes but the entry stays visible. Any idea how to get rid of it short from logging out and back in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got it. Had to kill dwm.exe via the task manager. Meh... Sorry to bother.