# Overlay (residual menu entry) in my Windows 10 desktop

Tags: windows-10, display, gui, overlay

I am getting an overlay in my Windows 10 desktop, and I don't know why. The overlay disappears when I hit ctrl + end + del, but do nothing and cancel. However, it pops up again after a while. I normally restart my computer when this thing happens and it goes away for a while.

[image: Weird overlay of windows menu item]

Comment: Related: [How to get rid of a single entry of the Windows Explorer context menu that is permanently displayed?](https://superuser.com/q/544691/354511)

Comment: P.S. What is ctrl + end + del?

Comment: Sorry, it was ctrl +  alt + del; this problem went away, probably after windows update.